# Django admin view without model

Tags: python, django, celery

Sorry, I don't have a code sample yet as I'm trying to work out if what I'm thinking can even be done.

I'm writing a Django app to manage Celery tasks. I'm using `django-celery-beat` for scheduled tasks but I'd like a similar admin interface to launch ad-hoc tasks with a form to accept parameters. I'd like it to sit with IP the admin section as this is all the app does; there are no other views right now.

All of the docs for `ModelAdmin` are based around custom fields for models but I don't think this object needs to be stored in a model as they are transient and data will be saved by the Celery task. From what I understand from the docs, you can't register a custom admin view without trying it to a model.

What I'm looking for is a custom view that's not tied to a model, just so I can create a custom form for these management commands in the admin section.

Ideas I've had:

- Create a dummy model with `managed = False` in the `Meta`
- Create a real model, but just never access it within the custom `ModelForm`
- Just create a view and add the URL into the admin section manually. This might be the simplest approach but I've been avoiding as I'm not sure what would be needed to tie it to the admin's auth system or displaying the link within the admin pages when everything else is auto generated.

Any pointers appreciated. I'll test all the reasonable answers and select the best as the right answer but will upvote for all responses.

Edit: @dejavu_cmd_delt made the great suggestion of [Flower](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I'd like to keep it all integrated within the `admin` section if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up :) It seemed too much of an anti-pattern so I abandoned the idea and created a simple custom model based on the one in `django_celery_beat` for ad-hoc tasks. This allowed me to piggy back on the task detection methods for the `ScheduledTask` modelform and use the `pre_save` hook to issue the task on creation to Celery. I then created a separate Django app to contain it and install alongside the main `django_celery_beat`.

Here's a copy of the model in case it's ever of use to anyone:

```
class AdhocTask(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    regtask = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    args = models.TextField(blank=True, default='[]',
                            help_text='JSON encoded positional args'
                            )
    kwargs = models.TextField(blank=True, default='{}',
                            help_text='JSON encoded keyword args'
                            )


# SendAdhocTask is my management command that parses the AdhocTask instance
# and sends the task to a Celery task queue.
signals.pre_save.connect(SendAdhocTask, sender=AdhocTask)
```